# "auth/app-not-authorized" in Firebase with react-native

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication

**auth/app-not-authorized**error only in phone authentication with device , i can store the data of email /password authentication, testing phone authentication in firebase react-native but not with device,i added the SHA 1, i checked the package name, project name, added google-services.json.i added the react-native-app,react-native-auth. **i am not getting otp to my device from firebase.**

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask good questions** carefully and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

When you say tested on device what do you mean ?
Tested locally or using internat test (Android) or TestFlight (iOS).
It really looks like an SHA-1 authorization question.

Comment: Thank u so much for your reply, run on the android device, I added SHA1 in firebase console from the android. when I added the phone number in testing mode, it added successfully in users tab, when I run on the device it does not sending the otp.